# Why am I getting a subscript out of range error when initializing an array in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, subscript

Trying to set the size of an array using a variable. I know that has to be done in a ReDim statement, but I am getting an error on the ReDim line telling me the subscript is out of range. How can I get that error on the line when I am defining the range?

Here's all relevant code:

```
Dim data As Worksheet, counts As Integer, sampleCol As Integer, sampleRows() As Integer, samples() As Variant, x As Long

Set data = Sheets("Data")
sampleCol = data.Cells.Find("Lab Sample ID").Column
samples = WorksheetFunction.Unique(data.Columns(sampleCol))

For Each sample in samples
     counts = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(data.Columns(sampleCol), sample)
     ReDim sampleRows(1 To counts)
     For x = 1 To counts
           sampleRows(x) = data.Cells.Find(sample).Row
     Next x
Next sample
```

Error is occurring on `ReDim sampleRows(1 To counts)`. I included the last for loop there which I do not think would have an impact on the cause of this error, but let me know if anyone thinks differently.

Comment: Likely `counts` = 0

Comment: I thought about this, but it should be impossible, given that the samples array is being defined by finding the unique values in a column, and then counts looks for the number of times each of those samples occurs in that same column

Comment: `samples` includes `Empty`. You're finding the unique values in the *entire column*, which likely includes blanks.

Comment: Side notes: use `Long`, not `Integer`. When using `Find`, always use the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters (you're only using `What`).

Comment: That was it! Added an If statement and no longer get the error. Thank you!

Comment: On the Long vs Integer debate, if my number will never ever be more than 32,000, is it still advised to use Long? Aren't you over allocating data or does it matter? I see this advice often, but never asked this question.

Comment: [It is still advised to use Long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: @kylemoely your work may not be always used by you, you may be promoted, move on to another job, and the data may someday change and the number could increase over 32,000. This is excel and with 1.1 million rows available on every worksheet I use Long for everything, I don't what my files to error out on someone else in case the dataset has changed.